# dc(1) and leading zeros

Tags: bash, sh, dc

I've got a shell script and I do some calculations with dc(1).

I need to have one number printed with leading zeros; I can't find an easy and straightforward way to do this with dc itself, but the manpage does mention:

> Z
>   Pops a value off the stack, calculates the number of digits
>   it has (or number of characters, if it
>   is a string)  and  pushes  that
>   number.  The **digit count for a
>   number does not include any leading
>   zeros**, even if those appear to the
>   right of the radix point.

Which sort of implies there is an easy and straightforward way ...

I know there are a zillion-and-one method of accomplishing this, and I the script is running happily with one of them. I'm just curious ;-)

Comment: I was going to do it in `bc` and dump out what it was doing, but GNU `bc` is not implemented as a frontend to `dc`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

Enter:

```
[lc1+dsc0nld>b]sb
[sddZdscld>bp]sa
999
12lax
```

Output:

```
000000999
```

Enter:

```
3lax
```

Output:

```
999
```

The original number is left on the stack after the macro ends. Registers used: `a` (macro), `b` (macro), `c` (count), `d` (digits).

Explanation:

Macro `a` does the setup, calls `b` and prints the original number.

- `sd` - store the number of digits to be output in register `d`
- `dZ` - duplicate the original number and push the count of its digits
- `dsc` - duplicate that count and store it in register `c`
- `ld>b` - load the desired digits from register `d`, if it's greater than the count then call macro `b`
- `p` - print the original number

Macro `b` outputs zeros until the count is greater than the number of desired digits

- `lc1+` - load the count from register `c` and increment it
- `dsc` - duplicate the count and store it back to register `c`
- `0n` - output a zero without a newline
- `ld>b` - load the desired digits from register `d`, if it's still greater than the incremented count then loop back to run macro `b` again, otherwise it will return to the caller (macro `a`)

To use an arbitrary leading character:

```
[lclkZ+dsclknld>b]sb
[sksddZdscld>bp]sa
999 14 [ ] lax
           999
[abc] 12 [-] lax
---------abc
```

In addition to the other registers, it uses `k` to store the character (which could actually be more than one):

```
[XYZ] 6 [def] lax
defXYZ
8 [ab] lax
abababXYZ
4 [ghjikl] lax
ghijklXYZ
```

The fill strings are used whole so the result may be longer than you asked for if the desired length number is larger than the length of the original string, but smaller than the length of the two strings (or integer multiples).

Comment: By the way, this could be done with a bunch of stack swapping without using as many registers, but registers make it easier.

Comment: That's a good answer -- Although a bit more complicated then I would have thought, but probably the best possible answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, albeit inelegant. This prints out 999 with 2 leading zeros. You'll need to duplicate the code for more digits.

```
#Push number to print on stack
999

# macro to print a zero
[[0]P]sa

# Print a zero if less than 5 digits
dZ5>a

# Print a zero if less than 4 digits
dZ4>a

# Print a zero if less than 3 digits
dZ3>a

# Print a zero if less than 2 digits
dZ2>a

# Print out number
p
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions given work for decimal numbers. For hex (as well as for any other input) radix use. e.g.

```
c=18A; dc <<< "16i${c^^}d0r[r1+r10/d0<G]dsGx4+r-[1-[0]nlGx]sY[d0<Y]dsGxr10op"
                ^ radix    formatted length ^       ^ leading symbol
```

You may also try

```
   c=19;   dc <<< "10i${c^^}d0r[r1+r10/d0<G]dsGx4+r-[1-[_]nlGx]sY[d0<Y]dsGxr10op"
   c=607;  dc <<< " 8i${c^^}d0r[r1+r10/d0<G]dsGx8+r-[1-[*]nlGx]sY[d0<Y]dsGxr10op"
   c=1001; dc <<< " 2i${c^^}d0r[r1+r10/d0<G]dsGx8+r-[1-[ ]nlGx]sY[d0<Y]dsGxr10op"
```

`G` and `Y` are the registers used. First the number of digits is counted on the stack, then the number of symbols to be printed.

```
c=607;  dc <<< "8i${c^^}d0r[r1+r10/d0<G]dsGx f 8+r-[1-[*]nlGx]sY f [d0<Y]dsGxr10op"
```